# disable buy button html5 player

Tags: soundcloud

I have a horror music website and have embedded some HTML5 players into it at www.horror-music.co.uk

I am trying to remove the buy button from the players and I am struggling in finding where to fit the `buying=false` parameter in my code

My original code is as follows without any adjustments, I was wondering if you would be kind enough to tell me where to insert the piece of code above into my code below so that the buy button does not display:

```
<iframe 
    width="100%" 
    height="166" 
    scrolling="no" 
    frameborder="no" 
    src="https://w.soundcloud.com/player/?url=https%3A//api.soundcloud.com/tracks/128832115&amp;color=4d1188&amp;auto_play=false&amp;show_artwork=false">
</iframe>
```

Comment: Hey, this is a setting in the sound / playlist that is embeded in this widget. It can be administered via "edit" link for the sound/playlist owner.

Answer (score 0):

```
<iframe 
    width="100%" 
    height="166" 
    scrolling="no" 
    frameborder="no" 
    src="https://w.soundcloud.com/player/?url=https%3A//api.soundcloud.com/tracks/128832115&amp;color=4d1188&amp;auto_play=false&amp;show_artwork=false&buying=false">
</iframe>
```

seems to work for me. So just add &buying=false at the end of the URL.